# parsing results of import.io search to table

Tags: javascript, import.io

Have set up several sites I'd like to search, created page in javascript that will allow me to input a value and search multiple connectors, but want to find better way to display the results. Currently, just get results separated by line break. Ideally, would like results in table with clickable links and the name of the source database added just as one sees when running search in Import.io program itself. Current code is below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canton Search 5000</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 1. Include the client library -->
<script src="https://cdn.import.io/js/2.0.0/importio.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure the library -->
<script type="text/javascript">
importio.init({
  "auth": {
    "userGuid": "3969d665-a06a-4738-9d1a-d691589d5f77",
    "apiKey": "CFKNykJp/dd5ee9rUUe2DWa/cNRmLLi2ibHQzs95ZuL6V4Culdq7c1wShLyO9Ed6CsRrgBJ4gP/Y72VaJPxezA=="
  },
  "host": "import.io"
});

// Data and done callbacks
var dataCallback = function(data) {
  console.log("Data received", data);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d = data[i];
    for (var k in d.data) {
      document.write("<i>" + k + "</i>: " + d.data[k] + "<br />");
    }
    document.write("<hr>");
  }
}
var doneCallback = function(data) {
  console.log("Done, all data:", data);
  document.write("<b>Done</b><hr>");
}

// 3. Do the query (when the function is called)
var doQuery = function() {
    var firstinputQuery = document.getElementById("name").value;
  // Query for tile Warrants
  importio.query({
    "connectorGuids": [
      "1e5989be-bcc3-4d29-91fd-003f8a603da9",
      "e1282ac5-8a98-4848-a907-9a0719ea51aa",
      "5e3e9f4b-d7f0-4b24-b646-62455cb2f174"
    ],
    "input": {
      "name": firstinputQuery,

    }
  }, { "data": dataCallback, "done": doneCallback });
}


window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("unselectall").onchange = function()  {Check(document.myform)};
};  

</script>
 <body>

<p>
Name:&nbsp<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="enter name here">
<p><tr>


</form>


    <br><button onclick="doQuery()">Search Them Cantons</button>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? What problems are you experiencing? _I don't know how to do it_ is not an appreciated problem/question among SO.

Comment: @dbf I've gotten the results in more or less the format I'd like using jquery, but only for one connector. I can't seem to figure out how to introduce the new code into the above. Tried substituting the below for the document.write commands above, but not working correctly for me. Also can't sort out how to make returned result a link. Very new to all this as you can probbaly tell.

   `for(var i =0;i< json.results.length;i++) {
                 var title = json.results[i].company_name;
             var venue = json.results[i].document;
                 var date = json.results[i].pdf; `